# Zsh history as array

Tags: shell, zsh

For some reason, I can't, for the life of me, get `zsh` to produce an array containing one line from the entire shell history per element. (i.e. `hist_arr[1] == $(history 1 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d ' ' -f 3-), hist_arr[2] == $(history 2 2 | tr -s " " | cut -d ' ' -f 3-), ... <for ten thousand lines>`). I'd like to compute the whole array in a single step, so it's more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hist_arr[1]=$(history 1 1)` works fine, but contains redundant history number.
If that is your problem then simple remove it, eg. this way:

```
hist_arr[1]=$(history 1 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d ' ' -f 3-)
```

**Edit:**

If you want to assign to table all element from history file then

```
IFS=$'
'
hist_arr=( $(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$1=""; sub(/\;/, "")}'1 .zsh_history) )
```

should work.

Comment: Well, that's insanely inefficient. My history has thousands of items, and running a loop and manually setting each element will spawn thousands of subprocess, be super slow... etc. I'd like to compute the whole array in one step.

Comment: Then your question was not precise, see the edit of my answer.

Comment: `hist_array=("${(@fOa)$(fc -ln 1)}")`